# determine hyperparameters used during training from saved XGBoost model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I have a model trained in Sagemaker as a file and can load and ultimately score it locally like so:

```
local_model_path = "model.tar.gz"
with tarfile.open(local_model_path) as tar:
    tar.extractall()

model = xgb.XGBRegressor() 
model.load_model("xgboost-model")
```

I wonder, how I can establish the hyperparameters used to fit the saved model. I do not think that these lines of code work (i.e. they do not show the hyperparameters the model was trained with):

```
booster = model.get_booster()
print(booster.save_config())

print(model.get_xgb_params())
```

How can I establish/check the actually used hyper parameters? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you test these lines of code? they do work for me locally, the booster will not have the hyperparameters but the model instance will

Answer (score 1):

Ok, forget the other answer which I deleted.

This one works for me, I don't know why  get_xgb_params() should not work.

```
model = xgb.XGBRegressor() 
model.load_model("xgboost-model")

model.get_xgb_params()
```

Comment: I tried this previously but it returns 'monotone_constraints': '()' eventhough I set them ...

Comment: Well, then the answer is correct with regards to the original question, these are the commands to show the hyperparameters used - get_xgb_params() or get_params().  It seems you see the hyperparams, but not the monotone_constraints you set.  I did a test,  added 'monotone_constraints':'(1,-1)' to my hyperparams, trained it, run get_xgb_params() and I get 'min_child_weight': 1,
 'monotone_constraints': '(1,-1)',
 'n_jobs': 0 ... I think you need to rephrase your question to "why are my monotone_constraints not showing up in get_xgb_params() ?" or something like that

Comment: the monotone_constraints are just one example. The issue with the other answer  (hidden) is that I cannot get the complete string. As I said I even tried ext_file = open("test.txt", "w") n = text_file.write(str(model.score)) text_file.close() but this is cut off in the string written to the file as well. so not possible to check/test ...

Comment: Right, forget that hidden answer, it's just a summary. The 2nd answer should show full, in addition to get_params().  I guess I misunderstood your question.  I assume you see all the hyperparameters with these commands, but they are not what you think are right.  Well, that's another issue, you might have to show more information (i.e. training code, etc) to get more answers from others, good luck.